# Expected standard deviation of probabilistic sample

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, sampling

Let's say I have a collection of $n$ individuals, each individual is associated with a single value $x_i$, with $i=1,2,3,...n$. I now gather a sample of $s$ individuals from this collection, without replacement. $s>1$. Each individual has a certain probability $p_i$ of being included in my sample, and I know this probability. My sample of $s$ individuals will have a certain standard deviation with respect to $x$.

My question: is there a way to calculate the expected standard deviation of $x$ of my sample, given: all individuals' values $x$, all individual's probabilities $p$, and my sample size $s$? If I were to randomly draw my sample infinitely many times, what would the average sample standard deviation be?

Comment: You have to define what is "sampling without replacement" in the case of unequal probabilities. I would guess that if the first chosen object is $i$, then the second is taken with probabilities $p_j/(1-p_i)$, $i\neq j$ etc. (It seems to me that in this form the question was already asked on math.SE but I didn't find.) Another possibility is that you can take $i$th object with probability $p_i$ or not take it with probability $1-p_i$ and consider the sample conditioned to have size $s$. Please clarify.